# Need some steps to integrate UNO wasm to an angular project

Tags: uno-platform

I tried creating a UNO wasm project and it looks promising. but i wanted to use the executables of the wasm files in an angular project and load the UI created in wasm in the angular component. Can you please helpe mwith some steps or a sample project?

Answer (score 1):

At present time (and likely up until .NET 7), hosting a WebAssembly application or library is not yet supported by the .NET runtime, aside from hosting the app in an iFrame.